# UnicodeEncodeError when parsing XML using cElementTree within Applescript

Tags: python, applescript, celementtree

Apologies if this is a duplicate or something really obvious, but please bear with me as I'm new to Python. I'm trying to use cElementTree (Python 2.7.5) to parse an XML file within Applescript. The XML file contains some fields with non-ASCII text encoded as entities, such as `<foo>caf&#233;</foo>`.

Running the following basic code in Terminal outputs pairs of tags and tag contents as expected:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
tree = etree.parse("myfile.xml", parser=parser)
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
    print child.tag, child.text
```

But when I run that same code from within Applescript using `do shell script`, I get the dreaded **UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)**.

I found that if I change my `print` line to

```
    print [child.tag, child.text]
```

then I do get a string containing XML tag/value pairs wrapped in [''], but any non-ASCII characters then get passed onto Applescript as the literal Unicode character string (so I end up with `u'caf\\xe9'`).

I tried a couple of things, including a.) reading the .xml file into a string and using .fromstring instead of .parse, b.) trying to convert the .xml file to str before importing it into cElementTree, c.) just sticking .encode wherever I could to see if I could avoid the ASCII codec, but no solution yet. I'm stuck using Applescript as a container, unfortunately. Thanks in advance for advice!

Answer (score 0):

You need to [encode](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) at least `child.text` into something that Applescript can handle.  If you want the character entity references back, this will do it:

```
print child.tag.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace'), child.text.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
```

Or if it can handle something like utf-8:

```
print child.tag.encode('utf-8'), child.text.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Both of these lines give the following error: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

Maybe I'm running up against the limitations of Applescript...

Comment: That means it's hitting some elements that don't have text - you can either just skip them (`if child.text: print...`) or use some other replacement (`if child.text is None: child.text = ''`).  Or `str(child.text).encode...`.

Answer (score 0):

Not AppleScript's fault - it's Python being "helpful" by guessing for you what output encoding to use. (Unfortunately, it guesses differently depending whether or not a terminal is attached.)

Simplest solution (Python 2.6+) is to set the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable before invoking `python`:

```
do shell script "export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8; /usr/bin/python '/path/to/script.py'"
```

or:

```
do shell script "export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8; /usr/bin/python << EOF

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# your Python code goes here...

print u'A Møøse once bit my sister ...'

EOF"
```

Comment: Curiously, adding this before invoking cElementTree didn't seem to have any effect. I still got the UnicodeEncodeError on the print command.

Comment: It's a Unix environment variable (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). Putting it in the Python code won't work - it has to go in the shell code as shown above.

Comment: BTW, are you aware System Events.app has an XML Suite? It's not particularly great (mind you, neither is ElementTree) but if your needs are modest then it might do you and avoid having to step outside AppleScript. Or there's Satimage's XMLLib.osax, which is a little tedious and crusty but quite usable IIRC. Or if you're on 10.7+ and Cocoa APIs don't faze you, you could even create a script from the the Cocoa-AppleScript Applet.app template, allowing it to use Cocoa's NSXML classes via the AppleScript-ObjC bridge.